# Image jaggerred edges while applying perspective, C#

Tags: c#, image, interpolation, perspective

Facing some issues with image warping. My application (C#, VS2010) takes as input an image and tiles it and applies perspective using a homography matrix. All that works fine and I get a tiled output image with the required perspective. But the output image has some jaggered edges and missing pixels.

This is a sample output from my application:
http://www.4shared.com/photo/vIeRhc9y/InterPol.html
(Enlarge the image to see the problem clearly)

Check out the jaggered edges and some missing white lines towards the top left corner of the image. I tried applying bicubic interpolation to the pixels based on the explanation provided here:
http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/imageprocess/

The output is slightly better, but most of the missing lines and jaggered edges remain. What can I do to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to do better ;) are you using System.Drawing or something else? I know how to make the quality really good with GDI+ but you should be able to get better results with [bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation). Are you doing any filtering?

For simple comparsion, just opening the image in Paint.NET and doing some resizing I'm not experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I am actually mapping the destination pixels to the source pixels in the image when warping. I am setting values for each and every pixel myself. I apply the bicubic interpolation to the source pixel and apply it to the destination pixel. I calculate the interpolated value for each and every pixel in the output image.

Comment: I suppose, this is what I require: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing , any idea how I could implement that. I mean, do I find the output image and then apply anti aliasing or do I have to do something at pixel level.

Comment: I've been trying to learn that myself sadly I don't know how to implement anti-aliasing. This though seems to be a good start, it's relativly simple. http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/antialiasing/methods.html and to be clear, it's going to involve a lot of cool signal processing math. What you wanna look into is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling which is pretty straight forward before going into more heavy stuff.